# How can I use RateLimiter's HttpClient DelegatingHandler with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

I've been using [RateLimiter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RateLimiter/) ([github](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/RateLimiter)) successfully with my project for a while now. I've recently discovered dependency injection and am attempting to migrate my code as-is to use this but I'm stuck on RateLimiter.

Normal usage from the docs is

```
var handler = TimeLimiter
        .GetFromMaxCountByInterval(25, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
        .AsDelegatingHandler();
var Client = new HttpClient(handler)
```

However if I try to replicate that during dependency injection

```
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyApiClient, MyApiClient>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.myapi.com/"))
               .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy())
               .AddHttpMessageHandler(() => TimeLimiter.GetFromMaxCountByInterval(25, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).AsDelegatingHandler());
     }
```

I receive the error:

```
[2021-05-17T21:58:00.116Z] Microsoft.Extensions.Http: The 'InnerHandler' property must be null. 'DelegatingHandler' instances provided to 'HttpMessageHandlerBuilder' must not be reused or cached.
[2021-05-17T21:58:00.117Z] Handler: 'ComposableAsync.DispatcherDelegatingHandler'.
[2021-05-17T21:58:00.122Z] An unhandled host error has occurred.
```

My class client structure (mostly for the sake of unit testing) looks like this:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class MyApiClient : HumbleHttpClient, IMyApiClient
{
    public MyApiClient(HttpClient client)
        : base(client)
    {
    }
}

public class HumbleHttpClient : IHttpClient
{
    public HumbleHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.Client = httpClient;
    }

    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string requestUri)
    {
        return this.Client.GetAsync(requestUri);
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content)
    {
        return this.Client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
    }
}

public interface IHttpClient
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string requestUri);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content);
    HttpClient Client { get; }
}
```

These are the docs I've been trying to follow:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: Very similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70466052/limit-outbound-requests-going-out-of-asp-net-core-web-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, but to fix this I believe you need to add the delegating handler as Transient as well.

So, in a typical scenario, you'd set up a `DelegatingHandler` as so:

```cs
public sealed class MyDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you need to register it; But here's the rub... You need to register the handler as Transient as well:

```cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpService, MyHttpService>()
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyDelegatingHandler>();

    // this needs to be added:
    builder.Services.AddTransient<MyDelegatingHandler>();
}
```

With that being said, you are in a unique situation as the handler you want to use is created at runtime from a 3rd party. You can make this work... Not 100% if it's correct, but it should work:

```cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    var handler = TimeLimiter
        .GetFromMaxCountByInterval(25, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
        .AsDelegatingHandler();

    builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyApiClient, MyApiClient>(
            client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.myapi.com/"))
        .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy())
        .AddHttpMessageHandler(() => handler);

    builder.Services.AddTransient(_ => handler);
}
```

### Edited to Add...

The issue you are seeing is with the `ComposableAsync` Nuget package. Specifically [this line](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/ComposableAsync/blob/e47a20178ff5a6e8a5bab5034dc6413720484bc2/ComposableAsync.Core/DelegatingHandler/DispatcherDelegatingHandler.cs#L21). The code *should not* be setting this property. ASP.NET Core should/will do it. Luckily for us it's just a simple extension method.

Let's write our own extension that does it the right way:

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class DispatcherExtension
    {
        private sealed class DispatcherDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
        {
            private readonly ComposableAsync.IDispatcher _Dispatcher;

            public DispatcherDelegatingHandler(ComposableAsync.IDispatcher dispatcher)
            {
                _Dispatcher = dispatcher;
            }

            protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                HttpRequestMessage request,
                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                return _Dispatcher.Enqueue(() =>
                    base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        public static DelegatingHandler AsDelegatingHandler(
            this ComposableAsync.IDispatcher dispatcher)
        {
            return new DispatcherDelegatingHandler(dispatcher);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to change your code to how I have it above with registering the hander. Also, make sure it's using the *new* extension instead of the one from the library.

I tested it and you can see it gets set properly:

[image: handler injection]

I would also consider opening a bug in the ComposableAsync github page.

Comment: This was a good thought but I still get hit with the error "InnerHandler property must not be null." I think the nuget package I'm using is at fault. In their constructor they explicitly set InnerHandler which is probably the source of this problem.
public DispatcherDelegatingHandler(IDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
      this._Dispatcher = dispatcher;
      this.InnerHandler = (HttpMessageHandler) new HttpClientHandler();
    }

Comment: @LukeSchoen -- So the problem is [this line](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/ComposableAsync/blob/e47a20178ff5a6e8a5bab5034dc6413720484bc2/ComposableAsync.Core/DelegatingHandler/DispatcherDelegatingHandler.cs#L21). He shouldn't be setting that. ASP.NET Core sets that.

Comment: @LukeSchoen -- Updated answer. That should fix it.

Comment: "I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, but to fix this I believe you need to add the delegating handler as Transient as well." It must be transient, since `DefaultHttpClientFactory` pools/caches the http message handlers, so that they are reused for better performance and avoiding socket exhaustion. At the same time, they expire after (by default) 2 minutes and new instances replace them. This is to avoid e.g. DNS lookups going stale.