# Limit Outbound Requests going out of ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a requirement where I need to limit the number of outbound requests going to XYZ external API from my application. Assume I have to send a maximum of 3 requests in span of 1 minute to that external API from my API.

I am using RateLimiter Nuget package http://david-desmaisons.github.io/RateLimiter/ and below is my complete code and it's working fine till 7th request and after that, I am getting below error

> "The 'InnerHandler' property must be null. 'DelegatingHandler' instances provided to 'HttpMessageHandlerBuilder' must not be reused or cached.
> Handler: 'Application.DispatcherExtension+DispatcherDelegatingHandler'

**ConfigureServices  method**

```
var handler = TimeLimiter.GetFromMaxCountByInterval(3, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).AsDelegatingHandler();

services
                    .AddRefitClient<IService>()
                    .ConfigureHttpClient((services, client) =>
                    {
                        var config = services.GetRequiredService<TestServiceSettings>();
                        client.BaseAddress = config.BaseUri;
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
                            "Authorization",
                            "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(
                                Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{config.Login}:{config.Password}")));
                    })
                    .AddHttpMessageHandler(() => handler);

services.AddSingleton(_ => handler);
```

**Dispatcher Extension**

```
public static class DispatcherExtension
    {
        private sealed class DispatcherDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
        {
            private readonly ComposableAsync.IDispatcher _Dispatcher;

            public DispatcherDelegatingHandler(ComposableAsync.IDispatcher dispatcher)
            {
                _Dispatcher = dispatcher;
            }

            protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                HttpRequestMessage request,
                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                return _Dispatcher.Enqueue(() =>
                    base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        public static DelegatingHandler AsDelegatingHandler(
            this ComposableAsync.IDispatcher dispatcher)
        {
            return new DispatcherDelegatingHandler(dispatcher);
        }
    }
```

I searched all the articles but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved by returning a new instance of the message handler each time is invoked by the `configureHandler` delegate. As per the documentation given in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) it's mentioned there as

> The configureHandler delegate should return a new instance of the message handler each time it is invoked.

So the final code goes like this

**ConfigureServices Method**

```
var handler = TimeLimiter.GetFromMaxCountByInterval(3, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

services
    .AddRefitClient<IService>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient((services, client) =>
    {
         var config = services.GetRequiredService<TestServiceSettings>();
         client.BaseAddress = config.BaseUri;
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
               "Authorization",
               "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(
                      Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{config.Login}:{config.Password}")));
     })
     .AddHttpMessageHandler(() => handler.AsDelegateHandler());
```